# InputMultiplexer click button

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

on my app I have created a table with 2 buttons, the buttons only apear some times,I use a **InputMultiplexer** to handle the buttons and the mouse click events, my problem is that when I click on the table area , even with the table hidden , the program uses both inputProcessor ,
my question is:

**how to turn off the plexer.addProcessor(stage) when I'm not using and active when when the buttons appear ?**

```
    public void show() { 
.........................     some code      ..............                 
 tabela = new Table(skin);
    tabela.setBounds( 0, 50,Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth() , 250);// ocupa o ecra inteiro, mudar isto no jogo
    tabela.add(ObjetoJogo.botaoOP1);
    tabela.add(ObjetoJogo.botaoOP2);

    stage.addActor(tabela);



    MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor(this.app);

    InputMultiplexer plexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    plexer.addProcessor(inputProcessor);
    plexer.addProcessor(stage);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(plexer);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how and when you show your stage you could:

- Set a disabled/enabled flag on each actor.
- Set Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null) when the buttons should not be active
- Switch between two inputprocessors.